# angularjs function does not get invoked

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I have created a simple scenario to start learning, but for some reason the following code does not work:

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.addIneger = function (a, b) {
        alert();
        $scope.output= a + b;
    }
});
```

and here is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <Script src="javascript/angular.js"> </Script>
  <Script src="javascript/script.js"> </Script>
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
  <table ng-cntroller="myController">
    <th>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="a"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="b"/></td>
    </th>
    <th>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="output"/></td>
    </th>
    <th>
      <td>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addIneger(a,b)" />
      </td>
   </th>
 </table>
```

So as you can see, 2 textboxes get the numbers, and after clicking the button the result should be shown.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a syntax error/typo:

```
<table ng-cntroller="myController">
```

Change that to:

```
<table ng-controller="myController">
```

For the rest, what you are doing works perfectly except for the fact that you're not adding numbers but strings because you are using `type="text"` on your `input`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a" />
<input type="text" ng-model="b" />
```

So when you add them up it concats the two values `"2" + "3" = "23"`. You'll need to change your inputs to `type="number"`:

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="a" /><br>
 <input type="number" ng-model="b" /><br>
```

Or cast your values to numbers in your method:

```
$scope.addInteger = function (a, b) {
    $scope.output= new Number(a) + new Number(b);
}

// or

$scope.addInteger = function (a, b) {
    $scope.output= parseInt(a) + new parseInt(b);
}
```

Works perfectly:

```js
angular.module('App', []);

angular.module('App').controller('Controller', [
             '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.addInteger = function (a, b) {
            $scope.output= a + b;
        }
    }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="Controller">
        <input type="number" ng-model="a" /><br>
        <input type="number" ng-model="b" /><br>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addInteger(a,b)">
            Add integer
        </button><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="output" /><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u still when I just change those fields to number my code does not work and I understood ur javascript cod eis slightly different but I can not find my mistake what is wrong with my javascript code?

Comment: mine does not even invoke he mehod

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code as below. The probelm should be , when addIneger(a,b) invoke it doesn't send the values of a and b.

```
var app=angular.module("myModule",[]).controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.addIneger=function(){
    alert();
    $scope.output= $scope.a+$scope.b;
    }
    });

<html>
<head>
 <Script src="javascript/angular.js"> </Script>
 <Script src="javascript/script.js"> </Script>
 <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
<table ng-cntroller="myController">
<th>
     <td><input type="text" ng-model="a"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="b"/></td>
     </th>
    <th>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="output"/></td>
    </th>
        <th>
     <td>

      <button type="button" ng-click="addIneger()" />

     </td>
   </th>
  </table>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: thank u but since I am trying to learn i am very curious to see how I can make it work with addInteger(a,b)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
$scope.output = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
```

Comment: still not working it seems that even he function does not get invoked at all